# Heyzap Unity Id showing odd behaviour

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have integrated Heyzap in my unity project. I have publisher Id from a client and ads are not showing from that id. However, If I use my own publisher Id ads are working fine. Also, sometimes, ad shows infinitely, you close the ad, it shows again and so on (This is also happening only with client's id). I am totally clueless whats happening. Can somebody help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Would need to see some code to figure out the looping part. You are probably calling "Show Ad" from Update() or FixedUpdate() so it is looping over the call again and again. Use lots of `Debug.Log("");` statements to figure out where it is looping.

You need to make sure your clients HZ account is setup exactly like yours. Are the settings all the same? Are ads enabled? Are you using HeyZap mediation? If yes, are the other ad networks campaigns setup properly?